# Changes in one Select should apply to multiple Select's

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I was wondering if there is a way to update multiple `select` list when one is updated.

To clarify the problem. I have this layout

[image]

What I want to achieve is that when I change the value of `kaviar` in level one, the change is applied to the next levels aswell.

An example could be:

- Level 1

  - 0 x Grain
  - 3 x kaviar
- Level 2

  - 0 x Grain
  - 3 x kaviar
- Level 3

  - 0 x Grain
  - 3 x kaviar

now I want to change the amount in kaviar in level two to be 4. Which then automaticly would change the amount in level three as well. Which in the end will look something like this.

- Level 1

  - 0 x Grain
  - 3 x kaviar    // No change here
- Level 2

  - 0 x Grain
  - 4 x kaviar    // Added one here
- Level 3

  - 0 x Grain
  - 4 x kaviar    // This updated by itself

---

**If it help**

I've made this layout with angularJS and it looks like this

*Controller*

```
    $scope.template = {
        ressource: {
            level: [{
                id: 0,
                gain: [{
                    id: 0,
                    amount: 0,
                    ressource: $scope.ressources.basic[0]._id
                }]
            }]
        }
    };
```

*And the `HTML`*

```
       <div class="vertical-spacing">
            <label>Ressource gain per level</label>

            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="level in template.ressource.level track by $index" 
                    class="list-group-item" 
                    ng-hide="template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) === 0">
                    <span>
                        Level: {{ template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) }}
                    </span>

                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="" ng-click="removeLevel(level)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="gain in level.gain track by gain.id">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Amount</label>
                                    <input type="number" 
                                           class="form-control"
                                           ng-model="gain.amount" 
                                           min="1" 
                                           required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ressource</label>
                                    <select required 
                                            ng-model="gain.ressource" 
                                            ng-init="gain.ressource = gain.ressource || ressources.basic[0]"
                                            ng-options="ressource._id as ressource.name | capitalize for ressource in ressources.basic"
                                            class="form-control selectWidth">
                                        <option style="display:none" value="" disabled>select a ressource</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="removeGain(level, gain)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <span>
                        <a href="" ng-click="addGain(level)" ng-hide="(level.gain.length + 1) > ressources.basic.length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add ressource
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <span>
                <a href="" ng-click="addLevel()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add level
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: What you want? You need to could not apply to another select box if you select one select box?

Comment: Couldnt you use javascript to check with if and with else if statments...

Comment: I updated the question to explain what I want to achieve

Comment: You mean to say if you change the dropdown value in level one the selected  dropdown value of level 2 also should be changed. Is this what your requirement is?

Comment: Each level have the same resource items? Only the amount must change in each of the different levels?

Comment: @JagadishDharanikota Yes.

Comment: You need a directive or event that checks the resource level on select change and updates all the required variables.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a function called `ng-change` which allows me to register a change on any `input` tag in my code. Then I just made a function in my controller for the `ng-change` to call and through there manipulate the levels after the one I've changed.

Thanks all for the inputs ^^